# qmake when vs2008 and vs2010 installed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I couldn't generate **vs2010** solution using **qmake** qt5 , the generated project is vs2008 I have two vs2008,2010 installed , I add the

> path = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies;
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0;

but qmake still generate the old vs project 
qmake issue this warning

> WARNING: Generator: MSVC.NET: Found more than one version of Visual Studio, but none in your path! Fallback to lowest version (M
>   .NET 2010 (10.0), MSVC.NET 2008 (9.0))

Comment: Well, remove the old VS path from PATH?
See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448269/qmake-and-multiple-msvs-versions

Comment: I did that I removed the old vs, I think the problem is I did not set the correct path ,I don't know how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct path is : path = C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin

Comment: This solved my problem too, could you accept your answer for the good of all mankind?